# Laravel : call inherited controller functions in a view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a global controller (Controller.php) that loads different classes.
I have another controller (Admin.php) that extends from this controller and can therefore access the methods of the loaded classes (like my session class).

In my Admin view I would like to be able to use a method of my Session class in this way:

`<p>{{ $this->session->getUserData() }}</p>`

Where $this refers my admin controller

How do I do it?

Comment: Don’t. Views should _not_ be calling controller methods. Views are supposed to be a _view_ of your application’s state at any one time. Controllers take a request, use models to save/retrieve state, and then present that state in a view. So pass the user data from your controller to the views that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to do that but you can pass it to view from controller like this:

```
// your controller

$userData = $this->session->getUserData();

return view('yourView',compact('userData'));
```

in your view like this:

```
<p>{{ $userData }}</p>
```